# How to retain PORO Form object field inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a R-o-R Form object which takes in attributes and then saves those attributes to some nested objects, however, upon failing the validations, the input values disappear. Is there anyway to retain them?

```
class FormObject
 include ActiveModel::Model
 attr_accessor(:name, :date)
 
 def initialize(params = {})
  @params = params
 end

 def save
  return if invalid?
  no = NestedObject.new(nested_object_params)
  no.save
 end

 def nested_object_params
  @params.permit(:name, :date)
 end
end
```

and this is the controller

```
class Controller
 def new
  @form = FormObject.new
 end

 def create
  @form = FormObject.new(form_object_params)
  if @form.save
    redirect_to ...
  else
    render :new
  end
 end

 def form_object_params
  params.require(:form_object).permit(:name, :date)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have overridden the initialize method without calling super. This messes up the whole attibute mapping done by `ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment` which the form really relies on to be able to fetch the attributes of your model.

```
class FormObject
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor(:name, :date)
 
  def initialize(params = {})
    @params = params
    super
  end

  def save
    return if invalid?
    no = NestedObject.new(nested_object_params)
    no.save
  end

  def nested_object_params
    @params.permit(:name, :date)
  end
end
```

If you use `ActiveModel::Attributes` instead of Ruby's built in `attr_accessor` you get type casting just like with ActiveRecord backed attributes.

But this is a straight up disaster as you now have three different representations of the same data:

- the instance variables on your FormObject
- the hash stored in @params
- the attributes stored in NestedObject

Instead you should probally rethink this completely and use delegation:

```
class FormObject
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :object
  delegate :name, :name=, :date, :date=, :save, to: :object

  def intialize(**attributes)
    @object = NestedObject.new(attributes)
    super
  end
end
```